# Best practice for event handling with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the best practice for an event handler? I'm unsure if I should put the buttons with the function to trigger or if I should, like jQuery, wait for the button's on click event.

Usually you can do this:

```
$('.buttonOK').on('click', function(){
    alert('ok');
});
```

Or just add on the button the `javascript:ButtonAction().`

Which should I prefer?

Comment: [Best practice zombies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/1228)

Comment: Adding it not in the markup is better, but in the end it is a personal opinion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practices for where to add event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104525/best-practices-for-where-to-add-event-listeners)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Short answer:** definitely do it the first way. Event delegation is way more performant, but requires extra conditionals in your code, so
> it's basically a complexity versus performance tradeoff.
>
> **Longer Answer:** For a small number of elements, adding individual event handlers works fine. However, as you add more and more event
> handlers, the browser's performance begins to degrade. The reason is
> that listening for events is memory intensive.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26104827/12300287

Comment: So i should wait the html action from user such as click on the button and i use the function or i must define for the button to trigger a function?

Answer (score 0):

I am also new, but I have found a good practice is "functional programming".
which means you declare your function, then call it. This helps when there are multiple events where you want the event to take place eg.

```
function ok () {
            consol.log("ok");  //consol log is much less annoying for debugging
        }

        $(".buttonOK, .btnOK").click(ok);  // calls function on class button ok or btnOK
        $(document).keyup(function(e) {if (e.which === 13) {ok();}}); //callsfunction on enter
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi thanks, i'm not very new at programming but in javascript i just wanna get this point of best practise to know if in a big scaled platform CMS it will not delay the scripts.